# How to find on which linux interface LAN wire is connected?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, lan, ifconfig

I have a machine with 3 visible ethernet ports. However, ifconfig is showing 7 interfaces.

I have connected LAN wire on visible ethernet port but don't know name of linux interface on which LAN wire got attached.

How can I check it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ethtool to let the NIC light blink, i.e. `ethtool -p eth0`.

More here: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ethtool.8.html